# iOS: UITabBarController with Ad below it

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

How can I create a `UITabBarController` and add an ad below it? What's the best way? I mean, should you use several `UIWindow`s or how is it possible?

Please give me advice on how can I achieve it.

Comment: You should check out container views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @the4kman,

[image: Embed tabbar]

**Step 1** : Add `UIViewController`

**Step 2** : Add `Container view` inside `UIViewController` from **Step 1**

**Step 3** : Embed `UITabbarController` to `Container view`

**Step 4** : Add good Ads below `Container view`

All done, Enjoy!

Comment: No, add bottom constraint to Container view, update that constraint's constant. Remove ad object when not needed.

Comment: looks like it I push/present some other VC - it displays above the ad. So, I added new UIWindow to the bottom and now it works well